# Given $B \subseteq A$ and $x \in A$, x could also be in B

Tags: proof-verification

This statement should be true right?  If $B \subseteq A$ and $x \in A$, $\exists x(x \in B)$.  I was trying to prove this statement but my previous approach was wrong.

My previous approach involved misstating the property if $B \subseteq A$ then $B \land A = A$.  This obviously is wrong as it should be $B \land A = B$.

So this is my new proof.

Given $B \subseteq A$, $B \lor A = A$.  This means:

$\forall x(x \in (B \lor A) \leftrightarrow x \in A)$

The statement of interest is:

$\forall x(x \in A \rightarrow x \in (B \lor A)$

Thus if $x \in A$, x could be in B.  Or that $\exists x(x \in B)$.

Comment: The fact that $B\subseteq A$ tells us that $B\cap A=B$, not $A$.

Comment: Note:  the claim in the header is clearly false...did you mean to write $A\subseteq B$?

Comment: This is false. You cannot prove it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As stated, the statement you seek to prove is clearly wrong.  Perhaps you mistyped?

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing out the mistake.  Let me quickly review the question and my proof again.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking. Please edit your post for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a figure is worth 1000 words.

[image]

By the way, why do you need "and $x \in A$" in your title?

Comment: What if B is the empty set?

Comment: @JackPfaffinger:  Then the statement is false and any proof that doesn't exclude the empty set is invalid.

Comment: Yeah, that's what makes me wonder if he meant $x \in B$.

Comment: Me too.........

Comment: I realized that the property I used was wrong.  $B \subseteq A$ means $B \land A = B$.  With that said, the question should still be valid right?  As by the picture provided by David, there should at least be an x that is in A and B.